# How to save typeahead.js results only when user has selected a result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, typeahead

Question I would like to grab the value of the state once the user selects a state from the list. I have the following so far: However, the result is save every time a user types in a character and not when the user have selected a value:

```
  $('form').on("change", ".state", function(e){
    var $contextualDiv = $(e.target).closest('div');
    var $state = $contextualDiv.find('.state');
    $state.each(function(i,v){
         console.log($(v).val());
    });
    ...
```

It seems like this is also not the correct way to access the selected through the object. Based on the documentation, I should just be able to grab it through the line:

var $state = $('.state').typeahead('val');

This is my current code:

html:

```
<form>
    <div>
      <input class="state tt-input">
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

jquery/typeahead.js implementation:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var bh = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: {
          url: '/get_states/',
          prefetch: function(settings) {
            settings.type = "GET";
            return settings;
          }, 
        },
      });

  $('.state').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'states',
      source: bh,
  });

  var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
      return function findMatches(q, cb) {
      var matches, substringRegex;

      // an array that will be populated with substring matches
      matches = [];

      // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
      substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

      // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
      // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
      $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
        if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
          matches.push(str);
        }
      });

      cb(matches);
    };
  };
```

Please replace the variable 'airline' with 'state' in the pictures.
[image: Typeahead object]

[image: Value is correct.]

Answer (score 0):

The typeahead library triggers an event when the user selects an option. That event's name is `typeahead:select`. Here is the example provided in the [documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md):

```
$('.typeahead').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
   console.log('Selection: ' + suggestion);
});
```

You can adapt this to work for your implementation.

I think this will work:

```
$('form input.state').on("typeahead:select", function(e, suggestion) {
   console.log("Selection: ", suggestion);
   // OR
   // console.log("Selection", $(this).typeahead("val"));
});
```

Comment: I have modified what you suggested to:      $state.bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
      console.log('Selection: ' + suggestion);
    });  However, I have an suggestion: undefined error. Can I not store the object as $state?

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. I tried your solution but I just a result of 'undefined'. 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined' I created a jsfiddle.  Still not sure what is the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/tj7dremL/11/

Comment: @HC There are a lot of error in your example, the most important being that you're using a wrong selector for the input element. I've created a modified version of your fiddle that contains only the code necessary to retrieve the selected value https://jsfiddle.net/tv6eaou7/

Comment: The selectors are used for another purpose.  The idea is that I want to be able to repeat the html element called "trip". That's why I am contextually finding the .state element. If I use $this, the jquery won't be able to reference what 'this' is. Can I not do this contextually?

Comment: @HC Yes, you can do that contextually. The problem is that you're adding a new `typeahead:select` listener every time the `.state` input changes (at each key press). Also, you can only add this kind of event listener to an input that was initialised (you've previously called `$(....)..typeahead(....)` on it). Also, to access the element that triggered the event you need to use `$(this)` not `$this`.

Comment: So how would you implement this contextually? What I use the $state variable, typeahead saves an object to the variable. it's difficult to pull the values. Which I don't think is correct. How would you implement this contextually?